# Download not working on homepage

Tags: download

I just tried to download elementary OS after making a contribution and I am getting a page not found error when I click the download button in the popup.

Answer (score 2):

There was a temporary download issue on the website that has since [been resolved](https://github.com/elementary/website/pull/1528). You can always re-visit the website and enter $0 to re-try the download.